# How pctB of Bollinger bands is calculated from R?

Tags: r, stock

I got Bollinger band by using TTR(BBands) in R. Following is the part of the data:

```
  .dn          mavg       up        pctB
3.004265   13.216833   23.429402  0.303991525
```

and, close price of the row is:

```
9.08
```

Formular to get pctB is:

```
pctB <- (price - dn)/(up - dn)
```

but, I can't figure out how pctB from R is determined.
When I put each variables into the formula:

(9.08-3.004265)/(23.4294-3.004265) = 0.297464

As you see pctBs are different from R. How is it calculated? The formula does not work with the close price, dn and up.

Comment: Hey, TTR is used.

Comment: There is a `BBands` function in that?  Is that the one you used

Comment: Yes, BBands is used

Comment: You can look at the source code.  It is doing a moving average to calculate the 'dn', 'up

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
Price = (low+high+close)/3
```

https://www.fmlabs.com/reference/default.htm?url=Bollinger.htm